# Ajax запрос вместо сабмита

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html, javascript

Была форма регистрации. Захотелось мне сделать так, чтобы при сабмите отправлялся ajax запрос и возвращенные данные вставлялись в div (Ошибка или success). Но с формой такое провернуть  не удалось, т.к. action отправлялся на самого себя и пришлось удалить теги form. Вроде бы все норм, но введенные данные не возможно сохранить (в браузере), и собственно сабмит на ентер не работает. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы и формочка была, и ajax нормально работал?

Comment: Разобрался. Надо было просто в action вставить javascript:void(0); . Не додумался сразу, потому что js не знаю, а тут просто срочность.
JS выучу, обещаю :)

Comment: @MrGaliev, action вообще лучше оставить каким был, так при каких-то ошибках в JS или отключенном JS хотя бы форма регистрации не сломается. Для подобной задачи есть события и нужно делать их обработчики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верните теги form на место, воспользуйтесь обработчиком события onSubmit, в котором будет выполняться ajax-запрос. В самом простом виде можно записать так:

```
<form onsubmit="return isExists();">
    <div id="exists_result"></div>
    <input type="text" name="account" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>

<script>
     function isExists() {
          // выполянете ajax-запрос, получаете данные, проверяете их, выполняете требуемые действия
          return false;
     }
</script>
```

Если isExists() вернет false - форма отправлена не будет

Answer (score 0):

Есть прекрасная [библиотека](https://github.com/malsup/form/) для автоматизации этого процесса. Превращает любую обычную форму в ajax-форму без изменений в html-разметке.